# 0 sec javascript replace

Tags: javascript, load

I have a code it looks like this.
It basicly replace ''php echo'' with an image.
But... When i load or reload the page i can still see ''php echo'' i want that image to be loaded direcly in 0 sec so i dont need to see ''php echo'' and also load that image in 0 sec. /// Sorry for my bad english.

Video example: https://youtu.be/XFI7DIrlVcM

```html
<td id="X"><?php echo $row['11']; ?></td>

<script>
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())>= 0 && parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())< 10 && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/bgwZcHq.png">'
}
</script>
```

Comment: Then remove the `1` from the `td` and put it on the `td` as a data attribute.

Comment: or use css .How soon javascript can do this is dependent on numerous variables

Comment: There is an easy solution to that: `<td id="X"></td>`. Also images can take time to load.

Comment: I edited the thread start cause basicly i get ''1'' from this code: <?php echo $row['11']; ?>

Comment: you can hide it with css and unhide it with js when you inject the img

Comment: Smart solution .css make the number the same color. But still would be nice with 0 sec load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then remove the value from being the content of the `td` and put it on the `td` as a **[data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)**, which you can then retrieve in JavaScript with the **[`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)** property.

```html
<!-- Put the empty <img> element into the cell so that the DOM is built correct from the start -->
<td id="X" data-value="<?php echo $row['11']; ?>"><img id="replace" title=""></td>

<script>

// Get all the td elements in an array
var tdList = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("td"));

// Get a reference to the empty image element
var img = document.getElementById("replace");

// Loop over the array
tdList.forEach(function(td){
  var val = parseInt(td.dataset.value, 10);
  
  // Check the id first for better performance since we don't care 
  // about the value unless we have the right element:
  if(td.id === "X" && val >=0 && val < 10 ){
    // Now, we only have to update the image element, not rebuild the DOM
    replace.src = "http://i.imgur.com/bgwZcHq.png";
  }
});

</script>
```

Comment: This worked but... But how do i make the image load faster maybe another question but still. The question is still 0 sec.

Comment: @FastX You are never going to be able to get 0 seconds. Content takes time to down load to the client and you can't control how fast someone else's bandwidth will be. Additionally, the speed of the server comes into play as well. The best you can do is make the image have a very small file size and have your content hosted on a fast server.

Comment: @FastX You could hide then entire table by default and then on the load event of the image, unhide the table.

Comment: But it still feels like im doing somewthing wrong. Facebook and all other pages all loadtimes are very fast why is it slow on mine. I think its the way i use this javascript. Thing about it. First it needs to php echo then it needs to find whats inside the div and then replace it. Why not make it smarter in someway? Make it search or do that in a smarter way someother way. 0 sec way.

Comment: Btw what is this? Number 10? How does it effect the script and what does it do? `var val = parseInt(td.dataset.value, 10);`

Comment: @FastX That wasn't what you asked. You didn't say "Am I going about this the wrong way?" You asked how to fix the code you have. Facebook has thousands of servers spread all over the world so that you can get a fast geographical response. And, those are high volume optimized servers. And, they aren't relying on .php for their server side code.

Comment: @FastX The `10`, which is the second argument to `parseInt()` is the radix. It tells the JavaScript runtime what base number system to use. It's always recommended to supply this because some strings can be misinterpreted as octals or hex values.

Comment: Do i need it or can i remove it?

Comment: As I said, it's always recommended to use it. I think you are somehow getting the idea that more code equals a slower page. That's not true at all. Add all the code you need to build a working, scalable program.

Comment: Its hard do me to exaplain but i try. Think that i want to run same code but different numbers. Do i need to change that ''10'' number which you added?

Comment: As I said, no. The `10` means you are working with base 10 numbers (which I assume you are), rather than octals (base 8) or hex (base 16).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<td>` being rendered on the page as `<td>`s are only valid in a very specific context: within a `<tr>` of a `<table>`, which is why your `<td>` is not being picked up at all.

If you change `<td>` to `<span>` and run the same code, you'll get the expected results:

```js
var tdList = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for(var i=0; i< tdList.length; i++){ 
  if(parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())>= 0 && parseInt(tdList[i].innerHTML.trim())< 10 && tdList[i].getAttribute('id') == "X")
  tdList[i].innerHTML = '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/bgwZcHq.png" />'
}
```

```html
<span id="X">1</span>
```

Comment: The code is bigger then that i just made a small example. The code includes <tr> & <table>

Comment: I think it's obvious that the OP is just showing the relevant part of the table's code.

Comment: you also had a typo in the `<img>` -- take out `title="` as it is causing rendering issues.

Comment: `title` is absolutely valid (and often very desirable) in `img`.

Comment: Obvious? I didn't get that at all from the way the problem was presented.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious too.

Comment: But, he doesn't need to take it out. He just needs to add the closing quote and add a space to fix it.

Comment: Yes, or remove it.

Comment: The fact that it's there implies that the OP wants it.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks